# What does it mean : qq = qq || {}?

Tags: javascript

I have downloaded a javascript script and one of the first line is :

```
 qq = qq || {};
```

What does it mean?

Comment: init the object if it is not initialized

Comment: @Igor There is only one object there, `{}` -- `qq` is just a *variable* (or, if this is in the global context, a *property*)

Comment: @Felix Kling: then click "close" and mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @JoshDavis: I expect he did, Felix is pretty used to how SO works. The system automatically puts that comment in when you do that.

Comment: @Josh: Yep, these comments are automatically generated. And close votes expire after a while, I voted to close this question a year ago.

Comment: I didn't notice it was from last year, I thought it was from last week. Explains why I got the first "close" vote.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It checks `qq` for a pre-existing [truthy value](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript) or else (`||`) sets it as an empty object (`{}`).

In essence, it's purpose is to quickly ensure that any further references to qq will not be undefined, so you can check for properties of the object without your script breaking due to the fact that the variable isn't even a valid object in the first place.

Comment: It checks if it is "falsy" rather than simply whether it is defined or not. This usually works because `undefined` is a falsy value. But if it is defined and it is a falsy value then it will overwrite the existing value. `var qq = false; qq = qq || {}; q // {}`

Comment: Yep, that is true.  Clarified slightly.

Comment: Note: 0, and empty string are both considered "falsy".

Comment: **This doesn't check for "existence of the variable".** If the variable (or global property) is not bound this will *result in exception*. The word "exists" should not appear at all in this answer. Consider starting with "Checks the variables value..." or similar.

Comment: Ok, kinda a technical point, I'm just trying to convey the behavior and purpose in plain language, but I've changed the wording some to be more clear, and used the "truthy" word for exactness.

Comment: Your explanation looks pretty good to me. For the OP's edification, I'd just add that a slightly more correct version of this idiom would be something like `if (Object.prototype.toString.call(qq) !== "[object Object]") { qq = {}; }`, because the version `qq = qq || {}` will behave incorrectly if `qq === true` for example.

Comment: @Tchalvak I like(d) this answer because it's very succinct. The pedantic/pedagogical sides of me just leak out ;-)

Comment: Your answer is good for more info.  I was actually trying to look up the "assignment as an expression" idea to explain that, since I think that's the big thing that makes the code less clear.

Answer (score 7):

In JavaScript the `||` (logical-or) operator has this logic-table:

```
A      | B          | A || B
Truthy | Don't care | A   (guaranteed to be Truthy)
Falsy  | Don't care | B   (may be Truthy or Falsy)
```

(See [Truthy and Falsy in JavaScript](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript) for what the terms mean.)

Therefor, in the case of `qq = qq || {}`:

If `qq` initially evaluates to a Falsy value then the result of `qq || {}` is `{}` and thus (`{}`, a Truthy value) is assigned to `qq`. Otherwise, `qq` was initially a Truthy value and the result of `qq || {}` (which is the result of evaluating `qq`) is assigned to `qq`.

This is an *idiomatic guard* used to easily protect against "undefined" arguments, properties, and similar.

Some people may prefer to use the following near-equivalent construct instead:

```
if (!qq) {
  qq = {}
}
```

This latter case, however, will only assign to `qq` if `qq` was initially Falsy; the form `qq = qq || {}` always makes the assignment, but such "overhead" is so trite it should not be used as justification to not use the approach.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

Explanation:

```
    qq = qq || {};
// ^^ is equal to iself, but if it does not exist, 
//       then it is equal to an empty object
```

For example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    qq = qq || {};
    qq[i] = 'something!';
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/dr5Ra/

Comment: Calling `=` 'equal' is a bit misleading: 'assign' is the better term here.

Answer (score 3):

The answers here so far miss out an important point. The OP says that the script *starts* with

```
qq = qq || {};
```

If so, and if `qq` hasn't been declared anywhere (no `var qq` at global scope, no `window.qq = ...`), that code will throw a `ReferenceError`. It will not just default `qq`.

In contrast, if the code were:

```
var qq = qq || {};
```

That would be *very different indeed*. It would do this:

1. The `var qq` part would be processed prior to any step-by-step code in the script. If there is already a global `qq` variable, it will be a no-op. If there isn't, it create a global `qq` variable with the initial value `undefined`.
2. When step-by-step execution reaches that line, the right-hand side of the assignment is evaluated like this:

   - If `qq` has a "falsey" value (`0`, `""`, `undefined`, `false`, `NaN`, or `null`), the expression `qq || {}` evalutes to `{}`.
   - If `qq` has a "truthy" value (anything not falsey), the expression evalutes to `qq`.

   (For more details: [*JavaScript's Curiously-Powerful `||` Operator*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html).)
3. The result of the right-hand-side is assigned to `qq`.

The `var` makes a **big** difference.

Answer (score 1):

qq will receive qq or will be a new object (`{}`) if it didn't exist.