# Significance of qq in javascript

Tags: javascript

I read the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390297/what-does-it-mean-qq-qq) and understand what the code

```
var qq = qq || {};
```

is doing, but what is the significance of qq in general.  Is it just common practice to use qq as opposed to zz or bb or ag?  Or does it have to be the letters qq?

If it does have to be the letters qq, then what is qq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be simply a quick variable name, like foo, bar, and baz.

Answer (score 2):

It has no particular significance. It's just a random variable name.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a variable name. The same construct would work with zz, or bb, or ag, or bz, or tg, or hr, or eq, or po, or ly, or ed, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `qq` has no special meaning in Javascript. If you come across it, **it's probably related to a FileUploaderBasic library inside of your codebase**.

The project [File Uploader](http://github.com/valums/file-uploader) which became [Fine Uploader](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader) depends on `window.qq` as an object that it can attach methods/properties to. You can see in [the code](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/24ed927e890331b6c4cbe39e926be2ae81ad30e3/client/js/ajax.requester.js#L3) that things are attached to a globally defined `qq` object, and it's even listed as a [predefined global variable in File Uploader's jshint config](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/24ed927e890331b6c4cbe39e926be2ae81ad30e3/.jshintrc#L113).